# What's up with all the spam

Tags: bug, spam

I am receiving spam edits like https://cooking.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10302 
on my posts, this is the 3rds time in the past week,
I use a dozen stackexchange websites and cooking.SE is the only one ever to have this problem, what is going on?

Since these spam edits are done by "anonymous user" I imagine there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the suggested edit history and this seems to be an isolated problem. It is only one post on the site which has had these problems, and it happens to be yours. There does not seem to be a software bug anywhere, just a single person trying to game the system. "Anonymous user" just means that somebody who does not have an account on Seasoned advice suggested the edit, this is made possible by design.

I will try to find a good solution with the team, but I think that there is already some system in place which will block suggested edits from an IP address if there are too many rejects in a short time. Probably 3 times in a week is too low to reach the threshold.

If I learn something more, I will add to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, I've never had any similar problem on any of the other sites, what it different here? are the anon users allowed to suggest edits here but not on other SE sites? and since I received the alert (red number thing at the top left of the page) 3 times so far, I think either they are repeating their attempt or there is a problem with the website software,

Comment: Anonymous users are allowed to suggest edits everywhere; try it for yourself on a site you haven't signed up for yet. And the spammer did indeed try repeatedly, even using different text (but always spammy) on all three occasions.

Answer (score 2):

It has been happening specifically to this thread (perhaps my post more than others, I don't know, but I do know that it has been happening to other posts on the same thread too). I have rejected a dozen or more spammy vandalism attempts in the past week or ten days, at least three or four times just today. It's really getting annoying. SAJ tried protecting the thread, but it didn't work. Can we get rid of the ganache hater with a shoe fetish?

[Ganache by pouring before fondanting a cake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40567/ganache-by-pouring-before-fondanting-a-cake)

Comment: The handbag and shoe spam happens over the entire SE network. It'd be posted by a botnet where infected computers would get a list of URLs to try posting to so I've noticed the same questions get hit, occasionally 3 or 4 times within minutes.

Comment: We're now looking at maybe 70Xs?

Comment: @rumtscho edited my post on the thread by incorporating the comments to the post into the post itself. Somehow, making the post longer helps make it safer. I don't know how, but it seems to be working. Thanks Rummy, I was really getting sick of it.

Comment: The @ to address someone only works in the comments under a post someone commented on, so I think I was the only one that got that message ;-)

Comment: Oh well, I wasn't sure if that would work or not. Sorry to bother you :)

Answer (score 1):

I see bad spam edits from time to time in the suggested edit queue.

I have never really paid attention to who they target or the frequency; I just reject them and move on.

I suspect what is happening is that when they happen to hit one of your posts, you get the notice, and so it is more apparent to you that this sometimes happens.

As to why SA, and not other sites:  obviously, we are more tasty!

Comment: +1 for being tasty